# How to prefer Nuget assemblies over SDK assemblies?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I just updated my Visual Studio version and got a new SDK version (Blend) installed. I previously used an assembly (System.Windows.Interactivity.dll) via Nuget that is now also provided by the SDK. Visual Studio now uses the SDK one instead of the Nuget version. Both assemblies have the same version but actually differ in their provided types. This is why I cannot compile anymore.

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to always prefer the assemblies from a Nuget package over the installed ones? I want to compile my code without considering about the installed SDKs on the current machine. This is why I prefer the Nuget way

Comment: @ mamuesstack, which kind of app did you really create in your VS IDE? Does VS add this dll file automatically during you create an app or you just add this reference manually? For example, if we create the  Silverlight App, the nuget package will cover that dll file we added manually.

Comment: It's a common C# class library project

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio do you upgrade? Installing SDK will not change projects' References. Please show your detailed steps that how do you upgrade Visual Studio and install the SDK, which could help us reproduce this issue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that this is an unusual VS behavior. It seems that it was a Resharper cache issue. I updated my question accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, in my case, it was a Resharper cache issue. Resharper showed an error and pointing to the SDK assembly. After clearing the cache manually and restarting Visual Studio it referenced the nuget assembly again. The errors then disappeared

Comment: Thanks for share your solution here. Please mark your answer, which is benefit to other communities who has the same issue.